# How to find and write down the prime numbers between 2 numbers?

Tags: c#

I'm new to the programming world and I wanted to start with c# and some prime numbers.
I'm trying to get to 2 numbers from the user and then check if there is any prime between these 2 numbers and of course print it in another textbox but it seems that I cannot do it the right way. can anyone help? Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int count;
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        for (int c = x; c <= y; c++)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
            {
                int z = x % i;
                if (z == 0)
                {
                    count++;
                    if (count <= 2)
                    {
                        textBox3.Text = x.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that _"it seems that i cannot do it the right way"_ is very vague. What is wrong with your code as it stands?

Comment: Two observations: your `i`-loop goes up to `x`,  should that not be `c` (not including `c` itself, of course, or you're always going to find two divisors). And _if_ you find a number, `textBox3.Text = x.ToString();` replaces the contents of the textbox, you'll want something like `textBox3.Text += x.ToString();`. Honestly, try putting a breakpoint and using the Step function of your IDE to go through the code line by line.

Comment: Every `x` inside the inner loop should be replaced with `c`. That's one thing.

Comment: @John i started the app and write 2 number 'for example 20  55' and it just shows me 20. the first part of the problem is 20 isnt prime. i only asked for prime.and the second part is even if 20 is prime it just shows 20.not 21,22,23,24...,55.

Comment: @CompuChip i did what you said and it kinda works but it isnt what i want i'm using 1 , 10 in the text box and the thing that shows is 1,2. well thats a start  guess but where should i us break points so that i can get the whole prime numbers?

Comment: As a remark, if you can name something, you might want to make it a function. Consider this code: `for (int c = x; c <= y; c++) { if(isPrime(c) { print(c); } }`. Far more readable and easier to test, wouldn't you say? (Of course if written in several lines with indentations.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int count;
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

            Boolean flag = true; ;
            for (int k = x; k <= y; k++)
            {   
             //  loop the iterations for k times
                for (int i = 2; i <k; i++)
                {
                    if ((k % i) == 0)
                    {
                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (flag == true)
                {
                    if(textBox3.Text!="")
                        textBox3.Text +=",";
                     textBox3.Text += k.ToString() ;
                }
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation as to how your answer solves OP's problem. "Try this -> code" isn't very helpful for understanding what's wrong.

Comment: the problem that it shows 1 and only number x is gone and now it just shows 2 numbers x,x+1. and it aint showing the prime numbers it just shows the numbers without calculating.

Comment: @Yuvraj Mule it doesn't shows the numbers in the textbox neither.
i didn't even think about c# being so hard to learn.

Comment: @ArminShabani  I've edited code and its working properly.  In your code you started inner loop from 1 which is not correct. you always get z=0 for all numbers when you devide by 1.
A number which is divisible by 1 and itself is called prime number. 
Prime number contains only 2 factors i.e 1 and the self number.